# Confused about volumes_from and volumes usage in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am trying to understand - maybe I already did maybe not - the differences between `volumes_from` and `volumes` usage in a `docker-compose.yml` file. I have read docs already but from there is not so clear to me so I am doing a real exercise.

I have the following setup:

- a root directory
- a directory named `php-apache` with a `Dockerfile` under root
- a directory named `mongo` with a `Dockerfile` under root
- a `docker-compose.yml` file under root

> Note: If it's not clear to you, take a look [here](https://github.com/reypm/php55-dev/tree/mongodb-test) and everything exposed down below is right there as well (`mongodb-test` branch)

- At `php-apache/Dockerfile` I have the following entry:

  ```
  VOLUME /data /data
  ```
- At `mongo/Dockerfile` I have the following entry:

  ```
  VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
  ```
- At `docker-compose.yml` I have the following:

  ```
  version: '2'
  services:
      php-apache:
          container_name: "php55-dev"
          image: reynierpm/php55-dev
          ports:
              - "80:80"
          environment:
              PHP_ERROR_REPORTING: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE'
          volumes:
              - ~/mmi:/var/www
          volumes_from:
              - volumes_data
      mongo:
          container_name: "mongodb"
          image: reynierpm/mongodb
          ports:
              - "27017:27017"
          volumes_from:
              - volumes_data
      volumes_data:
          image: tianon/true
          volumes:
              - ~/data/mongo:/data/db
              - ~/data:/data
  ```

This is what I am understanding from that setup:

- The image `reynierpm/php55-dev` will expose a `/data` directory and this will be mapped to `~data:/data` in `tianon/true` image
- The image `reynierpm/mongodb` will expose a `/data/db` to the outside and mapped to `/data/configdb` internally then the `/data/db` is mapped to `~/data/mongo:/data/db` in `tianon/true` image.

Is a mess in my head right now because what do I want to achieve is the following:

- Keep mapped the code on the host to the container (this line `<path_on_host>:/var/www` on `docker-compose.yml`)
- Keep data stored on a local directory in the host

So, it's fine what I am doing? Feel free to made any modification at this setup since I am still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The image reynierpm/php55-dev will expose a /data directory and this will be mapped to ~data:/data in tianon/true image

It's better to say it will mapped to your `~/data` on docker host. Please note  that there will be a `/data/db` from the second volume too.

> The image reynierpm/mongodb will expose a /data/db to the outside and mapped to /data/configdb internally then the /data/db is mapped to ~/data/mongo:/data/db in tianon/true image.

This container will be the same as php-apache in terms of volumes from 
volume_data container.

In case of your objectives:

If your code is in `~/mni/` you are fine. You are mounting mongoDB database directory to php-apache container, I don't think you need that.

You need to create a `user defined network` for your container connectivity or link containers (legacy). To create user defined network:

```
docker network create  --driver bridge <yournetwork name>
```

You don't need a DOC. Thats why I removed the third container. I also fixed the unnecessary volume mappings.

Updated Docker file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    php-apache:
        container_name: "php55-dev"
        image: reynierpm/php55-dev
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        environment:
            PHP_ERROR_REPORTING: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE'
        volumes:
            - ~/mmi:/var/www
        volumes_from:
            - volumes_data
    mongo:
        container_name: "mongodb"
        image: reynierpm/mongodb
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes_from:
            - volumes_data
    volumes_data:
        image: tianon/true
        volumes:
            - ~/data/mongo:/data/db
            - ~/data:/data
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: <your network name>
```

Please note you have to call your mongo container from your web application by its name, in your case `mongodb`.

Comment: Can you add a possible setup with `user defined network` since link is legacy as per your answer? I should be able to access any Mongo DB from PHP-Apache container I think this is what you said

Comment: Sure, can you give me your source image names? so i can test the setup too?

Comment: everything you need is on the repository. I haven't created the Mongo DB image just yet so you maybe want to remove the `image` and add `build` statement instead. The image `reynierpm/php55-dev` is already on Dockerhub

Comment: I havent tested the docker file yet.

Comment: this docker file is working fine by me, any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I can not test at this moment but I will as soon as I can, for now thx, will be back with news